# Is it possible to make the start menu appear on secondary display via win key?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, group-policy, start-menu, windows-key

Obviously, the Windows key will open the start menu on the primary display, this is somewhat inconvenient for multiple displays (dual monitors), having to travel all the way across every time.

Is it possible to have the start menu pop up on the secondary display when it's being used/in focus?

Comment: Is this settings available/work for you? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5943-start-menu-open-main-last-display-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I learned that this feature isn't supported on windows 10.

https://imgur.com/a/71RM8Jt

Comment: The tutorial is for Windows 10. Maybe not for a later version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out windows 10 doesn't support this feature.

[image: Management Console policy]

Comment: Note, you are allowed to tick your answer and you should.  It finalises the question

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I've set a reminder to do so once 48 hours has passed.